# issue while finding the xpath for span located inside div/h2 inside document

Tags: xpath

/*
      Returning visitors login

```
    <h2>
        <label for="ctl00_Login2_UserName" id="ctl00_Login2_UserNameLabel">Email</label>

        <br />

        <input name="ctl00$Login2$UserName" type="text" value="pallavi@ensarm.com" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_Login2_UserName" class="formstyle2" style="width:150px;" />

        <span id="ctl00_Login2_UserNameRequired" title="User Name is required." style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>

        <br />
        <br />

        <label for="ctl00_Login2_Password" id="ctl00_Login2_PasswordLabel">Password</label>

        <br />

        <input name="ctl00$Login2$Password" type="password" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_Login2_Password" class="formstyle2" style="width:150px;" />

        <span id="ctl00_Login2_PasswordRequired" title="Password is required." style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>

        <a id="ctl00_Login2_ForgottenPasswordLink" href="ForgottenPassword.aspx">Forgotten password?</a>
    </h2>

    <h2 align="right">
        <span id="ctl00_Login2_FailureText" style="color:Red;">Your login attempt was not successful.  Please try again.</span>

        <div class="button_right button_fixedwidth">
            <a id="ctl00_Login2_ibnLogin" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$Login2$ibnLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Login2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Login</a>
        </div>
    </h2>
</div>
```

*/

Above is my html pagesource i want xpath expression of span with id ctl00_Login2_FailureText. which is located inside div/h2

I have tried the fololowing xpath but its not working:
//span[@id='ctl00_Login2_FailureText' and contains(text(),'Your account has been temporarily locked because of a maximum number of incorrect login attempts.')]

Comment: `span` with `@id = 'ctl00_Login2_FailureText'` doesn't contain `Your account has been temporarily locked because of a maximum number of incorrect login attempts.` in provided XML sample...

Answer (score 0):

Better try it:

(change "text()" with ".")

```
//div/h2/span[@id='ctl00_Login2_FailureText' and contains(.,'Your account has been temporarily locked because of a maximum number of incorrect login attempts.')]
```